# filter array based on another arrays dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to JS. I want to apply filter on array based on other arrays. For example : Filter `data` array based on property names from `colNames` and values from `Values` array. The  `colNames` and `Values` arrays can have any length (not always 2).

```js
var data = [{
      "name": "Tiger Nixon",
      "position": "System Architect",
      "salary": "320800",
      "start_date": "2011\/04\/25",
      "office": "Edinburgh",
      "rating": "5421"
    },
    {
      "name": "Garrett Winters",
      "position": "Accountant",
      "salary": "170750",
      "start_date": "2011\/07\/25",
      "office": "Tokyo",
      "rating": "8422"
    },
    {
      "name": "Garrett Winters",
      "position": "Analyst",
      "salary": "170750",
      "start_date": "2011\/07\/25",
      "office": "Tokyo",
      "rating": "8422"
    },
    {
      "name": "Ashton Cox",
      "position": "Junior Technical Author",
      "salary": "86000",
      "start_date": "2009\/01\/12",
      "office": "San Francisco",
      "rating": "1562"
    },
    {
      "name": "Cedric Kelly",
      "position": "Senior Javascript Developer",
      "salary": "433060",
      "start_date": "2012\/03\/29",
      "office": "Edinburgh",
      "rating": "6224"
    }
  ]
  
  var colNames = ['name', 'position']
  var Values = ['Garrett Winters', 'Accountant']
```

**Expected Outcome**

```
   [{
      "name": "Garrett Winters",
      "position": "Accountant",
      "salary": "170750",
      "start_date": "2011\/07\/25",
      "office": "Tokyo",
      "rating": "8422"
    }]
```

Comment: what is the expected outcome

Comment: Just added in the post. Thanks

Comment: so does the colNames and Values contain key values from same object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could filter with the iteration of all keys and check with the values.

```js
const
    data = [{ name: "Tiger Nixon", position: "System Architect", salary: "320800", start_date: "2011\\/04\\/25", office: "Edinburgh", rating: "5421" }, { name: "Garrett Winters", position: "Accountant", salary: "170750", start_date: "2011\\/07\\/25", office: "Tokyo", rating: "8422" }, { name: "Garrett Winters", position: "Analyst", salary: "170750", start_date: "2011\\/07\\/25", office: "Tokyo", rating: "8422" }, { name: "Ashton Cox", position: "Junior Technical Author", salary: "86000", start_date: "2009\\/01\\/12", office: "San Francisco", rating: "1562" }, { name: "Cedric Kelly", position: "Senior Javascript Developer", salary: "433060", start_date: "2012\\/03\\/29", office: "Edinburgh", rating: "6224" }],
    cols = ['name', 'position'],
    values = ['Garrett Winters', 'Accountant'],
    result = data.filter(o => cols.every((k, i) => o[k] === values[i]));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```